# Не отображается в постах имя пользователя Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, авторизация, devise

При создания поста в блоге, на Rails не отображается имя  зарегистрированного пользователя. Вот модели приложения 
Модель **user.rb**

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable,:confirmable, :validatable
             has_many :posts 
    end
```

Модель **post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates:title, presence:true, length:{minimum:5}
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Когда я файле **show.html.erb** использую код для вывода пользователя

```
<h2>Пользователь <%= @post.user %></h2>
<h1><%=@post.title %> </h1>
<p><%=@post.body %></p>
<p>
```

не каких данных, не выводит о пользователи, а если я сделаю такой код `<%= @post.users.username %>` то ведет такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот созданная миграция **User**

```
class AddUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
   add_column :users, :username, :string
   add_index :users, :username, unique: true 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас для модели `User` указана связь один-ко-многим с моделью `Post` (у автора может быть много постов), но судя по скрину ошибки во вьюхе вы пытаетесь получить обратную ситуацию (у поста много авторов). Нужно либо изменить связи на прямо противоположные, что вряд ли, либо вызывать вместо `@post.users.username` > `@post.user.username`.

Comment: Поменял значения вот такая ошибка NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing /home/ali/Рабочий стол/relsa work0/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6
              

<h2>Пользователь <%=@post.user.username %></h2>
<h1><%=@post.title %> </h1>

<p><%=@post.body %></p>

Comment: Вероятно, в контроллере что-то происходит или не происходит, но во вьюху переменная `@post` приезжает без `.user`. Попробуйте повторить тоже самое в рельсовой консоли или сдампите из контроллера и посмотрите, что содержит `@post`.

Comment: извините, я новичок как это правильно сделать в консоле ?

Comment: Начните отсюда — http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails